# MySQL insert with multiple fields and where clause

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to construct a query for a cron that will run.

```
mysql_query("UPDATE `stocks` SET price='$pricez', open='$openz', high='$highz', low='$lowz', change='$changez', time='$times', percent='$percentz' WHERE symbol = '$symbolz' ");
```

The error I get is

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'change='-0.10', time='1406050151', percent='-0.35%' WHERE symbol = 'ALMB.CO'' at line 1
```

Scavenged SOF and have yet to find a solution.

Comment: Any reserved words being used?  yep.. change wrap change in back ticks `change`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reserved words just bit you:
Change is a reserved word thus needs to be escaped: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html

```
mysql_query("UPDATE `stocks` SET price='$pricez', open='$openz', high='$highz', 
low='$lowz', `change`='$changez', time='$times', percent='$percentz' WHERE symbol = '$symbolz' ");
```

So what is a reserved word?

They are words the engine uses to interpert specific requested commands.  When these words are used as identifiers for tables or columns they must be treated in a specific manner usually escaping the words for the RDBMS involved.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are using some reserved words for column names: Change and Time
You can escape these with backticks (`), or choose new coumn names

```
UPDATE `stocks` 
SET     `price`='$pricez', 
        `open`='$openz', 
        `high`='$highz', 
        `low`='$lowz', 
        `change`='$changez', 
        `time`='$times', 
        `percent`='$percentz' 
WHERE symbol = '$symbolz'
```

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html  Open, time and percent don't appear on reserved words list for MySQL.  Change does however.

Comment: Sorry was thinking T-SQL.  Time is definitely on the list.

Comment: I like the edit with everything in backticks, that's the way to go there's no doubt then +1

Comment: I lied Time is a keyword but can be used without backticks.  When In doubt escape everything!

Comment: @andrew while it does reduce the risk, it obfuscates the underlying problem to future maintenance.  I'd much rather see it used only when needed; and only when it's too late to change the column name.